# Fastest & Most Core way to replace "\r\n" with "\n" in a file?

Tags: sed, replace, tr

I suppose `tr` is a more core method and thus probably a faster way to replace things within a given file.

However tr can only replace equal amounts of characters. meaning...

2 characters can only be replaced with 2 characters which means replacing

`\r\n` with `\n` is out of the question via `tr`

is the next best option `sed` ?

is sed the most core and fastest way to replacing `\r\n` with `\n` in a file given the lack of capabilities in tr ?

would like an example if possible.

Comment: What exactly does "Most Core" mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With `sed`, you can do:

```
sed 's/\r$//'
```

The same way can do with `tr`, you only have to remove `\r`:

```
tr -d '\r'
```

although this will remove *all* instances of `\r`, not necessary followed by `\n`.

Comment: These two are not identical. The first with replace '\r\n' with '\n' (effectively), but the second will remove all '\r' wherever they appear. It's uncommon for carriage-return to appear in a text file, other than at the end of the line, but it can happen.

Comment: Usage: `sed 's/\r$//' input_file.txt > output_file.txt`

Comment: Why is it `\r$` and not `\r\n/\n`? I mean where does it replace against `\n`?

Comment: Ah ok `$` is line-ending, which means "remove \r from the end of the line".

Answer (score 6):

OR use `dos2unix`

for example:

```
$ echo -ne "1\r\n2" |  od -A n -t x1
 31 0d 0a 32
$ echo -ne "1\r\n2" | dos2unix | od -A n -t x1
 31 0a 32
```

we can see replace `\r\n` with `\n`

Comment: This is not a program in the OP list but in my opinion the cleanest way to do the job. I personally use it every time I need such conversion.